# Display a web-page through iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to show a [stackOverflow page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987297/bi-directional-css-height-animation) through the `iframe` but it is not working.

```html
<iframe
    title="page in a page"
    width="300"
    height="200"
    src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987297/bi-directional-css-height-animation">
</iframe>
```

Some solutions on internet are saying to remove `https:` from the **url** then it will work. But it is also not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Many websites do not allow being rendered inside iFrames for security reasons. This is the case here as well with stackoverflow. You can see that in the response headers of the requested page:

```
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
```

You can read more about `x-frame-options` for example on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options).

Comment: then t means I can't show that page in an iframe ?

Comment: that is correct, to be precise: the browser is instructed by the page (in this case stackoverflow) to not allow loading that url in an iframe.

Comment: okay thanks for help. I think **PHP** can do this easily by using `file_get_contents`.

Comment: I can't answer this question because it is closed now.